# protocol buffers get EnumDescriptor *

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, protocol-buffers

I have an UpdateType enum in my protocol buffers message

I want to modify it using reflections, for that I need EnumDescriptor.

[Google protocol buffers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#EnumDescriptor) says

```
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
namespace google::protobuf

Describes an enum type defined in a .proto file.

To get the EnumDescriptor for a generated enum type, call TypeName_descriptor(). Use DescriptorPool to construct your own descriptors.
```

How can I get EnumDescriptor? where is TypeName_descriptor() func?

Comment: I had the same question, I upvoted the question. Caused by a stupid comment in google protobuf. Why give wrong information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get enum_descriptor from FieldDescriptor.

Just use FieldDescriptor::enum_type() to get EnumDescriptor*

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Typo in your answer, you mean:
FieldDescriptor::enum_type()

Comment: It did help, and I have upvoted your answer as well as the question.